# Print a BLOB document

Tags: .net, printing, blob

I am trying to find a way to print a document that is stored as a BLOB without having to first open it, the filename is stored as well so I have the extension of the file available. The only idea I have had is to save it in the users temporary folder and then point the PrintDocument class to it but im sure theres a better way of doing it then that.

Thankyou to all who contribute.

Comment: Do you actually want to print out the file source? What kind of file is this? If it's big that's a lot of trees. If you actually want to print a file format properly (like an image or document) you're going to need to run it through some sort of software capable of interpreting it.

Comment: @ AndrewM I want to print whatever the document is, so if its a .doc file it will print like a word document, if its a .jpg it will print an image etc...

Answer (score 0):

since you have the filename, you could try using ShellExecute to print the file. you would have to save it to a temporary location, though.

I also think it wouldn't be that much different from using PrintDocument, as it also uses the default Print action for the file type. Also, i think you will have to pinvoke it.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid saving the file to a temp location, this way would get the same results as using PrintDocument but would be harder work surely?

Comment: i think it would be better performance-wise, since you will be pinvoking from win32 api. it will be easier if done from vc++. but convenience-wise it would be better to stick with PrintDocument (especially if you are in C# or VB). i don't think you would have a choice, though, because to print a document you would have to know how to print it:
- via it's file type and using default actions, as you are already doing
- or by opening the application used to create it

Comment: Ok thankyou for your help, I guess ill give PrintDocument a go as im in C#.